# Is it possibile to use a WiiMote as a controller for an Android phone?

Tags: android, wiimote

I was wondering if it was possible to use a WiiMote as a game controller (for emulators) on an Android phone?  I suppose it would have to map as a hardware keyboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Look up `Wiimote controller` on the Android Market.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use (up to 4) wiimote controller(s) with your android phone, you can simply use the (free) *Wiimote Controller* app.

The Wiimote(s) will register as a seperate input method, and should be **compatible with every program** (that allows assignment of keys to actions.)

**Do note however, that this app do not work together with the HTC Sense interface!**

(you can download it by scanning this QR-code with the barcode scanner on your andoid phone.)
[image: Wiimote Controler]

Comment: Anyone got this working with HTC magic? I don't have Sense UI installed, but apparently it's still won't work for me - bluetooth stack issue or something :(